ALTIUM Creating a pattern between unions
I have repeating ADC channels in Altium, 8 channels. I created different unions for all channels.  I made an arrangement for the 1. channel. Then, I selected the first channel and the first union and copied the positions and rotations in the pcblist to the other union channels. Thus, I have 8 ADC circuits with the same pattern. Now, my goal is to distribute these unions equally, 4 to the right and 4 to the left from the middle of the PCB. .How can I achieve this?
I used the align components and distribute horizontally option, but it applies it to all components and breaks the pattern.



This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

"room" is the name of the Altium feature you are looking for

Or, without using any fancy feature, you could lay down 8 fiducials and use align and distribute to space them out.  Then copy+paste down your copies using the fiducial points as the reference.

I think if you can make rooms for all of them you can dot it. For example:

Putting the ADC components inside the rooms as follows:



Then, by using align to bottom command:


You can make rooms as follows: Design-> Rooms-> Place Rectangular Rooms

The problem here is that when you give the align to bottom command to the rooms, the rooms with components are synchronized independently of the components. So this is not a solution.
